# JavaScript if/elsif statement bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some sort of elsif statment bug I can't find:

My JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/64/

Jquery:

```
$('#slider1, #slider2, #slider3, #slider4, #slider5').bind('slide', function (event, ui)
{
    var num = this.id.replace('slider','');

if(parseInt(num) == 1) {
        $label = $('#boksTimer' + num).html( (ui.value / 31 * 60).toFixed(0) + ' GODT' );
}
elseif(parseInt(num) == 2) {
        $label = $('#boksTimer' + num).html( (ui.value / 31 * 60).toFixed(0) + ' SUPER' );
}
else {
        $label = $('#boksTimer' + num).html( (ui.value / 31 * 60).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag' );
}
        $thumb = $(this).children('.ui-slider-handle');

    $label.css({
        top: $label.outerHeight(true),
        left :$thumb.position().left - ( $label.width() - $thumb.width() ) / 2
    });
});
```

Comment: For all we know, this code is supposed to do exactly what it is doing. You need to explain what's supposed to happen, what's not happening, and what you think is the problem.

Comment: After pasting your code in jsFiddle, you'll notice a button in the menu titled "JSLint". Click it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`elseif` is not a keyword.
You need a space.

Comment: @Railsbeginner: I approve of this message

Answer (score 2):

theres suppose to be a space between else and if `else if(parseInt(num) == 2) {`

Answer (score 2):

While @SLaks explained to you why your code didn't work, I think you should use this instead:

```
var text = ['GODT', 'SUPER'];

$('#slider1, #slider2, #slider3, #slider4, #slider5').bind('slide', function (event, ui)
{
    var num = parseInt( this.id.replace('slider','') ),
        $thumb = $(this).children('.ui-slider-handle'),
        $label = $('#boksTimer' + num)
                    .html( (ui.value / 31 * 60).toFixed(0) + ' ' + (text[num - 1] || 'min pr. dag') );  

    $label.css({
        top: $label.outerHeight(true),
        left :$thumb.position().left - ( $label.width() - $thumb.width() ) / 2
    });
});
```

It's much cleaner than a whole slew of if statements.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/68/